# uploading and downloading a encoded bitmap image to and from server using mysql and php

Tags: java, php, android, json, base64

I have a small project in which I have to upload and save 3 images in a table, on a remote mysql database. After that I have to fetch those images from the table and display in imageViews in my android application. Upload and downloads is done in two separate android applications.
I want to upload images with good quality but low size, so I'm compressing the images with bitmap compress technique and then encode it to string using base64, and then upload it to server.
In the server I have written a php file which receives the encoded string and saves it into the table(using longBlob).

my issues:
1.if I try to decode and save the image into the table in the php, I'm getting an error.
2.I directly saved the encoded image and retrieved it using json, but when I try to create a json object(to get the image) in the android code, its giving error like JSONException:value[{"imagePhoto":"/4AAQS....etc" and JSON.typemismatch and caused by:java.lang.nullpointerexception

I really don't know how to do this and I don't know whether my approach is right or wrong. Basically I just want the image to upload with less size and good quality, get saved and retrieved with good quality.

please help....thank you

code:
encoding the image

```
public String getImage(String path){
        try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(techFolder.getPath() + File.separator + path);
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0,stream);
        byte[] byte_arr=stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        String encodedString=Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedString;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

php file

```
<?php
//i skipped the login and db selection details

$imagePhoto=$_POST["imagePhoto"];
$imageAddress=$_POST["imageAddress"];
$imageSignature=$_POST["imageSignature"];
//$imagePhotoa=base64_decode($imagePhoto);
//$imageAddressa=base64_decode($imageAddress);
//$imageSignaturea=base64_decode($imageSignature);

$query="INSERT INTO  `a1597402_semapho` VALUES ('$imagePhoto', '$imageAddress', '$imageSignature')";

//executing query
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

        if ($result) { 
            $response["success"] = 1; 
            $response["message"] = "Succesfully submitted"; 
            die(json_encode($response)); 
        } else{ 
            $response["success"] = 0; 
            $response["message"] = "Failed to submit the details  "; 
            die(json_encode($response)); 
        }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

code for retrieving the image:

```
     public class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

    public static String getJSONFromUrl(String url,Boolean isParam,List<NameValuePair> params ) {

        // make HTTP request
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //checking for parameters to send to server
            if(isParam)
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8190);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
            {
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }
            byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();


//          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
//            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//            String line = null;
//            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//              //Log.d("stringff",line);
//                sb.append(line + "\n");
//            }

            is.close();
            //json = sb.toString();
            json=new String(imageData);
          Log.d("stringff",json);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // return JSON String

        return json;

    }

}
```

background task which calls jsonParser class

```
@Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                json = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(STATE_URL,false,params);
                Log.d("image", json);
                //parsing json string

                     try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("BREAK1","break1");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String image;
                    try {
                        image = jsonObj.getString("imagePhoto");
                        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), 0);
                        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                        i.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(json, Base64.DEFAULT);


                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload jpg files? If so then do not convert them to bitmap or something else first. Also do not encode to base64 as that causes for 30% more bytes to transfer. Also do not use json to upload images.

Comment: Stop using mysql functions in PHP, move to **mysqli** or **PDO** instead.

Comment: thanks guys...i found the solution